# How to find Spark's installation directory?

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache-spark

I want to change `spark-env.sh` . How can I find the installation directory in ubuntu??

I looked in the UI but didn't find anything.

```
whereis spark
```

result : `spark:`

Here's the log for locate command
    locate spark

```
/home/sys6002/.netbeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/temp/spark-ba1ea995-b959-43f4-ab6c-7d9f1ee5fcc1/blockmgr-db3a931b-7f1a-423e-b5da-b75a958a1909/11
/home/sys6002/.netbeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/temp/spark-ba1ea995-b959-43f4-ab6c-7d9f1ee5fcc1/blockmgr-db3a931b-7f1a-423e-b5da-b75a958a1909/13
/home/sys6002/.netbeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/temp/spark-ba1ea995-b959-43f4-ab6c-7d9f1ee5fcc1/httpd-16b4313e-72dc-4665-b4ac-df491869386d/files
/home/sys6002/.netbeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/temp/spark-ba1ea995-b959-43f4-ab6c-7d9f1ee5fcc1/httpd-16b4313e-72dc-4665-b4ac-df491869386d/jars
/home/sys6002/Desktop/diff spark hadoop.png
/home/sys6002/Desktop/sparkmain
/home/sys6002/Downloads/learning-spark-master.zip
/home/sys6002/Downloads/mongo-spark-master
/home/sys6002/Downloads/spark-1.5.1
/home/sys6002/Downloads/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6
/home/sys6002/Downloads/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6 (2)
/home/sys6002/Downloads/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
/home/sys6002/Downloads/spark-1.5.1-bin-without-hadoop
/home/sys6002/Downloads/spark-cassandra-connector-master
/home/sys6002/Downloads/spark-core_2.9.3-0.8.0-incubati
home/sys6002/anaconda3/pkgs/odo-0.3.2-np19py34_0/lib/python3.4/site-packages/odo/backends/tests/__pycache__/test_sparksql.cpython-34.pyc
/home/sys6002/spark-example/a.txt
/home/sys6002/spark-example/a.txt~
/home/sys6002/spark-example/pom.xml
/home/sys6002/spark-example/pom.xml~
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/test
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java/com
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java/com/geekcap
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java/com/geekcap/javaworld
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java/com/geekcap/javaworld/App.java
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java/com/geekcap/javaworld/WordCount.java~
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java/com/geekcap/javaworld/sparkexample
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java/com/geekcap/javaworld/sparkexample/WordCount.java
/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/main/java/com/geekcap/javaworld/sparkexample/WordCount.java~

/home/sys6002/spark-example/src/test/java/com/geekcap/javaworld/AppTest.java
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/lightspark:lightspark.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sparkleshare:sparkleshare-invite-opener.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sparkleshare:sparkleshare.desktop
```

Comment: Do you have /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh ?

Comment: Anil instead of searching spark search specific file, something like spark-env.sh

Comment: @HRgiger, searched for `spark-env.sh `. No result

Comment: did you try:  find / -name 'spark-env.sh' 2>/dev/null

Comment: @Mike `locate spark-env.sh ` this one no result

Comment: Less possibility but search when you are root so you will make sure you didnt install under different user

Comment: According to the documentation here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#overriding-configuration-directory  You should have environment variables defined SPARK_HOME/conf, but it appears it can also be overridden. "you can set SPARK_CONF_DIR. Spark will use the the configuration files (spark-defaults.conf, spark-env.sh, log4j.properties, etc) from this directory."

Comment: @Mike, find command too resulted in nothing

Comment: Also, if you did the install today, the locate database may not be updated yet.  I would still try the find command.  A little clunky, but it doesn't rely on the file system database that gets updated only periodically. **replied a little too slow**

Comment: Is it possible the default install doesn't include it, so you need to create it?

Comment: `updatedb` will update the directory. I run it. Installed spark 10days back

Comment: From the documentation (same location): Note that conf/spark-env.sh does not exist by default when Spark is installed. However, you can copy conf/spark-env.sh.template to create it. Make sure you make the copy executable.

Comment: @Mike, with my knowledge about spark, definitely 'NO'

Comment: @Mike, also in another machine (with centOS), i saw the directory as `/opt/spark`

Comment: @Mike, about documentation but the file `conf/spark-env.sh.template ` existence is guranteed

Answer (score 35):

Run

```
echo 'sc.getConf.get("spark.home")' | spark-shell
```

After a moment your Spark home will be printed, you'll see something like this:

```
scala> sc.getConf.get("spark.home")
res0: String = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark
```

So in this case my Spark Home is `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark`

Comment: This did it for me. I actually have several homes, inside the /anaconda3 directory and inside my project's python virtual environment. That was really helpful! Thanks :)

Comment: Hm... It worked the first time. Ive used it to navigate to it and add conf directory and added spark-env.sh Then after that when I run it again now it says it cannot find valid SPARK_HOME...

Answer (score 18):

You can try these two commands:

1. `locate spark`
2. `whereis spark`

> **locate** - For each given
>          pattern, locate searches one or more databases of file names and
>          displays the file names that contain the pattern.  Patterns can
>          contain shell-style metacharacters: '*', '?', and '[]'.  The
>          metacharacters do not treat '/' or '.'  specially.  Therefore, a
>          pattern 'foo*bar' can match a file name that contains 'foo3/bar', and
>          a pattern '*duck*' can match a file name that contains 'lake/.ducky'.
>          Patterns that contain metacharacters should be quoted to protect them
>          from expansion by the shell.
>
> **whereis** locates source/binary and manuals sections for specified
>   files. The supplied names are first stripped of leading pathname
>   components and any (single) trailing extension of the form .ext, for
>   example, .c. Prefixes of s. resulting from use of source code control
>   are also dealt with. whereis then attempts to locate the desired
>   program in a list of standard Linux places.

Comment: all the results from locate command are directing to my Downloads directory. Which is not the one I'm looking for

Comment: Can you provide some output?

Comment: `whereis spark` result : `spark:`

Answer (score 7):

This also worked for me:

`cd $SPARK_HOME`

It will take you to the directory where Spark was installed, if that environment variable is set.

Answer (score 3):

You should search for `spark-shell` instead

```
whereis spark-shell
```

Typically this would resolve to a path like this `/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7`

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the home directory of Spark at all? You don't necessarily have to have a local installation of Spark to run Spark applications. You do need to have a local installation of Spark package to have Spark Standalone or to distribute it over YARN or Mesos clusters, but it doesn't seem to be your case.

You need jars and the Spark defaults will do the rest.

You can see the Web UI since it's up by default when you create a SparkContext instance.

All in all, Spark is in the project you're developing as a bunch of jars, and when your Spark application starts, it creates a SparkContext that depending on your master URL will connect to the runtime environment.

Environment variables in `spark-env.sh` can be easily set using `SparkContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Without a local directory how can i configure the memory&other options in `spark-env.sh`??

Comment: You only need `SparkContext` object. All you do in `spark-env.sh` translates to SparkContext and does have translations from env var to setting. What do you want to set? In the meantime, I added some (hopefully) useful content to the answer.

Comment: I agree that I can set then to the object. & I can see them in UI. But the fact is that is that the amount of RAM used is not getting affected by doing this way.

Comment: Please see here. http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Setting-spark-executor-memory-problem-td11429.html

Comment: It's been resolved on the mailing list so please add it here and mark as accepted answer. Thanks for a nice conversation!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jacek, I found that Spark is not installed in my machine and I was just using the spark libararies in my project.

To add more,to Run spark application in java project, You don't necessarily need `apache spark`, `scala` and `pyspark`.

Including jars will make your job done

Answer (score 0):

### **If you want to delete local data from Spark application in Mac**

Go to

```
~/Library/Containers/
```

**Then find folder has name got `spark` something**

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the directory of where Spark is, you can override the default directory by setting the environment variable `SPARK_CONF_DIR` to point to a directory of your liking. Then Spark will use that directory to locate `spark-defaults.conf`, `spark-env.sh`, etc. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#overriding-configuration-directory